# making a navbar with tab container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginnerat html css javascript . i am trying to build a navbar of a tutorial but there is an error with the javascript code . it is a navbar with a tab indicator which is responsive  but it is not working well .  i get the error (Array is not defined). i am not sure if it is something wrong with the function or if i am missing some line

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.lineicons.com/3.0/lineicons.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
    <div class="tab">
        <ul class="tab-items">
            <li class="tab-item">
                <a href="#" class="item-link"  onclick="select(this)"><i class="lni lni-home"></i> home </a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item">
                <a href="#" class="item-link"  onclick="select(this)">about </a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item">
                <a href="#" class="item-link"  onclick="select(this)">blog </a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item">
                <a href="#" class="item-link"  onclick="select(this)">community </a>
            </li>
            <li class="tab-item different">
                <a href="#" class="item-link"  onclick="select(this)"><i class="lni lni-user"></i> login </a>
            </li>
            <div class="tab-indicator"></div>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css code

```
.tab {
    max-width: 800%;
    padding: 0 2em;
    border-radius: 0 .5rem;
    background-color: #333;
    line-height: 4em;
    font-weight: bold;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 20px #000;
}
.tab-items {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-grid;
    grid-gap: 1em;
    transition: color 5s ease-in;
}
.tab-items> :nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/2;
}
.tab-items> :nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 2/3;
}
.tab-items> :nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 3/4;
}
.tab-items> :nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 4/5;
}
.tab-items> :nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 5/6;
}
.item-link:hover {
    color: #297;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.tab-indicator{
    height: 3px;
    background-color: yellow;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 0 0;
    grid-column: var(--index)/span 1 !important;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    align-self: end;
}
```

javascript code

```
function select(link){
    const item=link.parentNode;
    const tabs=item.parentNode;
    const index=Arrary.prototype.indexof.call(tabs.children, item);
    const items=tabs.querySelectorAll('.tab-item');
    tabs.style.setProperty('--index',index+1);
    items.forEach(item => items.classlist.remove('active'));
    item.classlist.add('active');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

"i get the error (Array is not defined)."

Are you sure that's the error? Copy the exact error message and post it here.

Reduce the code to the least amount of code that still triggers the problem. Remove everything unrelated to that error.

If you still can't find the source of the error by yourself after stripping down the example, you will have a lot more luck getting others to volunteer their time with a reduced example.

Debugging is a process.

Rather than tell you exactly where you messed up, it's best to let you figure it out and answer it yourself.